# Handling process exit from within a thread in a multi-threaded application

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

I have a multithreaded application. The application has the following set of threads:

1. The main thread that sleeps. All signals are blocked in this thread.
2. Thread t1 that does all the processing. All signals are blocked in this thread.
3. A signal handling thread (t2) setup by a third party component that I use. This thread waits only for the SIGINT and SIGKILL signals. all other signals are blocked in this thread.
4. My own custom signal handling thread (t3).

Now, for handling the process exit, I was sending a SIGUSR1 to my process. The signal would get caught by thread t3. Thread t3 would call the cleanup routine and exit. The problem here is that thread t3 tries to cleanup resources accessed by the other threads. This would result in intermittent crashes.

Obviously, my present solution does not have a graceful process exit handling. My question is how should one go about handling the process exit in such a scenario? How should the signal handling thread go about stopping the remaining threads and then doing a process exit?

Or is there a better way than sending signals (SIGUSR1) for process termination?

My application is written in C and runs on RHEL 5.

Comment: Why can't your third thread tell to the other one they have to stop ? Then you just have to wait for each thread to stop, and clean the resource once they are teminated. This looks more like a resource sharing problem than a signal  / exit problem

Comment: What does "t2" (the 3rd-party component thread) do when it receives `INT` or `TERM`?  Does it terminate the entire _process_ (as by `exit()`), does it terminate just itself (`pthread_exit()`) or what?

Answer (score 0):

Put a mutex on the cleanup routine so two threads don't try to clean up at once. The thread that wants to shut down should acquire the mutex and then tell other threads to shut down (whichever way you normally do that). This way only one thread should ever do the actual cleanup.

```
void cleanup()
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(m);
    if (!cleanup_done) {
        cleanup_done = 1;
        tell_other_threads_to_stop();
        wait_for_other_threads_to_finish();
        clean_up_common_resources();
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(m);
}
```

Alternatively you can lock all shared resources permanently, clean them up and terminate the entire process while holding the locks.

Comment: Threads should clean-up only their own resources, so there shouldn't be a need to serialize the clean-up. Serializing clean-up may cure a symptom but not the underlying issue that threads race to destroy the same object.

Comment: Hi mpartel/Maxim, the issue here is not that 2 threads try to cleanup the process. The issue is that I need to cleanup from only 1 thread i.e my signal handling thread.

Answer (score 0):

One good way to handle signals in a multi-threaded application is to have only one thread wait for signals, all other threads should have signals blocked. Normally, this is the main thread that initializes all components/libraries, creates other threads, waits for signals and terminates the application in an orderly fashion.

It is not clear why your application has threads 1 and 4. Thread 2 can do all the work and handle all signals (should probably be the main thread). Generally, it is not a good idea to let a third party component handle signals, so it may be better to block signals in thread 3.

The standard termination signals an application should handle are `SIGINT` (sent upon `ctrl-c` keystroke) and `SIGTERM` sent by `kill <app-pid>`.

Comment: Hi Maxim, I know that its always better to have only 1 thread handle all the signals. However, the thrid party component that I am using has broken this unwritten rule. Since I cannot afford to not use this component, I will need to live with their signal handling thread.

Comment: You can block signals in the third party thread. See [pthread_sigmask](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/sigprocmask.html).

Comment: I can't do that Maxim as the third party tool does its own specific cleanup in case of SIGINT and SIGKILL. And since its a third party tool I can't really influence them to change.

Comment: BTW, `SIGKILL` cannot be caught, blocked, or ignored, at least on Linux. Second, does that 3rd-party lib has a de-initialize function that you can call to terminate it cleanly? Anyway you can block the signals in the 3rd-party, handle the signals in your thread and when terminating unblock the signals in the lib and send it a `SIGINT`.

Comment: Maxim, I guess what I need to do is stop(cancel or kill) all other threads from within my signal handling thread. Once all the other threads are gone, I can safely call an exit from the signal handling thread. Would this work Maxim ?

Comment: I guess it is a typo, the 3rd party handles SIGINT and SIGTERM, not SIGKILL. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: My problem here is the 3rd party component does not expose any such de-initialize function. Another problem is I need to cleanup my global resources. Since the global resources could be in access in thread 2(t1), I need to stop/kill this thread before calling my cleanup routine in my signal handling thread.

Comment: Another option is to superimpose `pthread_create()` to get the thread id of the third-party thread and `pthread_join()` it (you can make it non-detached). Once the third-party thread received the signal and terminated, `pthread_join() returns and you can terminate the other threads.

Answer (score 0):

Your t3 has to cancel t1/t2 and wait for their terminations before calling exit() since race conditions exist here.

Don't be lazy in this situation because there are no other ways.

By the way, since your main() does nothing, you can simply finish it early with an explicit pthread_exit().